# C# - Deserializing Json in Json

Tags: c#, json

I have the following Json: http://pastebin.com/pd62g62w
How can I deserialize `"sensors"` and turn it into an array/list ?
I'm using Json.NET for the deserialization.

```
DeviceModel deviceModel = new DeviceModel();
deviceModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DeviceModel>(json);
```

My current code:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Homecheck.Models {
    public class DeviceModel {
        public string error { get; set; }

        public string errorType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_user")]
        public string user { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_serial")]
        public string serial { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it sounds like you need a `Sensor` class, and then a `List<Sensor>` in `DeviceModel`. (As an aside, I'd strongly recommend that you start using conventional .NET property names - `Error`, `ErrorType` etc.)

Comment: @Thank you for the suggestion. I didn't know that C# property names start with capitals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class for sensors objects

```
public class Sensor {
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "_description")]
    public bool Description { get; set; }
    /* and so on */
}
```

And then add it to your model as `IEnumerable<Sensor>` property:

```
public class DeviceModel {
    /* existing properties omitted */
    public IEnumerable<Sensor> Sensors { get; set; }
}
```

`IEnumerable<Sensor>` gives you an interface to go through all elements.
You can also use `IList<Sensor>` if you want list semantics (add, remove, access by index), or use array `Sensor[]` if you just want to have access by index.